# How to get a search folder criteria in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to edit a search folder in Outlook. But a search folder is treated as a regular folder:
in [this MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868545(v=office.15).aspx), MS informs that "*GetSearchFolders returns a Folders collection*".

I believe that, once I have the search folder filter, I will have to delete the current, edit the filter and create a new one - but that's the easy part. I have found e.g. [here](http://www.slipstick.com/developer/create-an-outlook-search-folder-using-vba/) how to create and delete search folders. Everywhere I find create and delete, but nobody seems to know how to edit it or get the filter that applies to it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outlook Object Model will not let you edit the search criteria of a Search folder.

You can either use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi, you can see the search criteria in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) if you select the search folder and click the IMAPIFolder button and go to the GetSearchCriteria tab) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (any language - I am also its author): it exposes the [RDOSearchFolder](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOSearchFolder.htm) object (lets you create and manage MAPI search folders) and [RDOStore2.Searches](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosearches.htm) collection - it exposes saved searches (backed up by MAPI search folders) visible under the Search Folders node in Outlook.

UPDATE: the following script will print the search criteria of all searches in the default profile:

```
set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
set Searches = Session.Stores.DefaultStore.Searches
for each Search in Searches
  Debug.Print  "-------------"
  Debug.Print Search.Name & ": "
  Debug.Print Search.SearchCriteria.AsSQL
next
```

Comment: I kept searching and got there - to Redemption. I think it will cover my needs, I will let you know.

Comment: Would you be able to share your code? I desperately need to figure out how to access the search criteria of a search folder. I'm trying Redemption but no luck.