# VBA Outlook - read the current explorer search filter

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to read the current filter of the `Explorer.Search` function.
I tried it with this code:

```
private sub read_old_filter()
    dim objExplorer as Outlook.Explorer
    dim oldFiler as String

    set objExplorer = Outlook.ActiveExplorer
    oldFilter = objExplorer.search
end sub
```

But `objExplorer.search` is a function, so it cant work.

I want to reuse the old filter. I have makros how filter for something like `strFilter = "received:(today OR yesterday)"`.
And the `private sub read_old_filter()` is in my userform. I want to connect the old filter and the new filter of the userform.

Can anyone help me?
Thanks for any commend and answer. Kind reguards, Nico

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is obviously not *directly* possible in Outlook VBA. Although there is a ActiveExplorer.CurrentView.Filter as well as an XML property of the View, this will not expose the current filter query/condition.

However upon searching I came across this thread which is mentioning Redemption which seems to provide what you need:
[How to get a search folder criteria in Outlook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020971/how-to-get-a-search-folder-criteria-in-outlook)

Hope this helps.

Comment: The Outlook object model works like charm. It doesn't provide a direct property, but looking at the VIEW properties gives the search string.

Comment: **Which** property then? I can't find it.

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev **Which** property then? I can't find it anywhere in the View object.

Comment: Thanks for help. That object you added your answer is very strong and I have to ask my line manager if I can use it for the search. If I get permission, I will post my code solution. Kind regards, Nico

Comment: @LocEngineer look for my solution in the second answer. Its another way, but I got what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I got a great Idea. I make in my `Modul1` global values. In this values are the filter options of the macros.
I save with an `Integer` the current filter number. A `Public Function` read the `Integer` and with `Select Case` it pass the right filter to the userform.

**Modul1**

```
Const FILTER_1 As String = ""                               'löscht alle filter
Const FILTER_2 As String = "followupflag:(followup flag)"   'zeigt nur Tasks an
Const FILTER_3 As String = "received:(today OR yesterday)"  'zeigt nur mails von heute und gestern
Dim filterUsed As Integer

'select right filter and save the number
Sub ViewFilter_all()
    filterUsed = 1
    Call filter_aktualisieren(FILTER_1)
End Sub
Sub onlyTasks()
    filterUsed = 2
    Call filter_aktualisieren(FILTER_2)
End Sub
Sub ViewFilter_today()
    filterUsed = 3
    Call filter_aktualisieren(FILTER_3)
End Sub
'search function for the macros
Private Sub filter_aktualisieren(strFilter As String)
    Dim objExplorer As Object
    Set objExplorer = Outlook.ActiveExplorer

    objExplorer.search strFilter, Outlook.OlSearchScope.olSearchScopeCurrentFolder
    objExplorer.Display
End Sub
'function to pass the filter to the userform
Public Function getFilterUsed() As String
    Select Case filterUsed
        Case 1
            getFilterUsed = FILTER_1
        Case 2
            getFilterUsed = FILTER_2
        Case 3
            getFilterUsed = FILTER_3
        Case Else
            getFilterUsed = "none"
    End Select
End Function
```

**Part of Userform**

```
Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'code....
    'vorFilter is a Global String in my Userform
    vorFilter = getFilterUsed()
    'code....
End Sub
```

Hope the Solution help other People too.

Comment: OK. Nice! But I must admit: I still have no clue how you're reading the current filter in use. You just set things, no hint how you're determining the currently active filter. Or am I just blind?

Comment: @LocEngineer you are right. I can’t read the current filter, but I saved the filters (filters for macros) and an `Integer` in the module. The Integer includes a number and this number points to the active filter. So I did not actually read the current filter, I read the current number and came with the number to the filter. That’s a way around the problem. It's not really a solution, but it works.